# Inequality with number of digits

Tags: number-theory, inequality

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two natural numbers that have an equal number $n$ of digits in their decimal expansions. The first $m$ digits (from left to right) of the numbers $a$ and $b$ are equal. Prove that if $m > \dfrac{n}{2}$, then $$a^{\frac{1}{n}}-b^{\frac{1}{n}} < \dfrac{1}{n}.$$

Let $a > b$. We notice that $a-b < 10^{n-m}$ and so $a-b < 10^{\frac{n}{2}}$. How do we continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

From the hypothesis, we can write

$$a=10^{n-m}x+y,\qquad\text{and}\qquad b=10^{n-m}x+y',$$

where $x,y$ and $y'$ are positive integers such that $y,y'<10^{n-m}$. Now,

$$a^{1/n}=(10^{n-m}x+y)^{1/n}\leq(10^{n-m}(x+1))^{1/n}=10^{1-m/n}(x+1)^{1/n}$$

and

$$b^{1/n}=(10^{n-m}x+y')^{1/n}\geq(10^{n-m}x)^{1/n}=10^{1-m/n}x^{1/n}.$$

Therefore

$$a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\leq 10^{1-m/n}(x+1)^{1/n}-10^{1-m/n}x^{1/n}=
10^{1-m/n}\left((x+1)^{1/n}-x^{1/n}\right).$$

But $m/n\geq1/2$, so $1-m/n\leq 1/2$, and hence

$$a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\leq \sqrt{10}\left((x+1)^{1/n}-x^{1/n}\right).$$

Now, since $(x+1)^{1/n}-x^{1/n}\leq \frac1nx^{1/n-1}$ (see below),

$$a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\leq \sqrt{10}\frac1nx^{1/n-1}\leq \frac{\sqrt{10}}{9^{1-1/n}}\frac1n.$$

For $n\geq3$,

$$a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\leq \frac{\sqrt{10}}{9^{2/3}}\frac1n<\frac1n,$$

and for $n<3$ there is nothing to prove.

**Note** (proof of the inequality $(x+1)^{1/n}-x^{1/n}\leq \frac1nx^{1/n-1}$): we write

$$(x+1)^{1/n}-x^{1/n}=x^{1/n}((1+1/x)^{1/n}-1)$$

and apply [**Bernoulli's inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) (note that $1/n<1$):

$$x^{1/n}((1+1/x)^{1/n}-1)\leq x^{1/n}\frac1{nx}=\frac1nx^{1/n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that $m$ is an integer, so $m > \frac n2 \implies m \ge \frac n2 + 1$. Therefore we have that $a-b \le 10^{\frac n2 - 1}$

Now consider the function $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{x}$, which is obiously continuous and differentiable. Now from the Mean Value Theorem we have that there exists a real number $c \in (a,b)$ s.t.

$$\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a-b} = f'(c) \iff \sqrt[n]{a} - \sqrt[n]{b} = \frac{1}{n\cdot c^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}(a-b)$$

Note that we have that $c>b>10^{n-1}$, so we have that: $\frac{1}{n\cdot c^{\frac{n-1}{n}}} < \frac{1}{n\cdot 10^{\frac{(n-1)^2}{n}}}$. Now:

$$\sqrt[n]{a} - \sqrt[n]{b} < \frac{1}{n\cdot 10^{\frac{(n-1)^2}{n}}}10^{\frac n2 - 1}$$

Now it's enough to prove that: $10^{\frac{(n-1)^2}{n}} \ge 10^{\frac n2 - 1}$, but this is trivial as $2(n-1)^2 \ge n(n-2) \iff n^2 - 2n + 2 \ge 0 \iff (n-1)^2 + 1 \ge 0$ is true for any $n$.

Also we can notice that $n \ge 3$ must hold, as otherwise we can't have $m > \frac n2$, unless $a=b$, which is trivial, but the solution already takes care of that.

Comment: The inequality $2(n-1)^2 \geq n^2$ holds for $n \geq 4$, not $n \geq 3$. How do we deal with the case that $n = 3$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 I was commenting from the phone last time up. Now maybe with the edit in the question you would be able to understand the proof, which should be fine.